# ARMA MLE - matrix setup

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, arma

I am trying to estimate ARMA(2,1) series parameters via ML, but unfortunatelly I am confused of setting up Matrix "Gamma" . I have seen plenty of articles regarding this, but it seems like this an obvious thing, that is not mentioned or described anywhere, i.e.:

"$L(\Gamma, X)= (2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}} \det(Γ)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left({-\frac{1}{2} X´ Γ^{-1} X}\right)$

where X n is the data, and $\Gamma$ depends in a complicated way on the
parameters"

Can anybody give me an advice please?
Thank You.